# Python open file statement is reading line from empty file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read a file using the following statement:

```
input = open("input.txt").read().split('\n')
```

So basically my objective is to read the file line by line and store results in an array. It works perfect when the file is not empty. When input file has only one line `len(input)` is 1, which is as expected.

But when the file is empty, `len(input)` still gives 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of python are you running? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @Nicarus i'm using 2.7.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `open("input.txt").readlines()`, not `open("input.txt").read().split("\n")`.  If you try `"".split("\n")` in the interpreter, you will see that the result is `['']`, not `[]`.

Comment: @ikis - you should mark this as the correct answer if it was your solution.

Comment: @Nicarus stack overflow didn't allow me to accept it within 10 mins. I have already attempted. Will do it as soon as it become available.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating a file gives you the lines, so you could use:

```
the_input = list(open("input.txt"))
```

though this will include the newline characters in the strings.

Comment: Thanks, I was curious. . . . . . .

Comment: (I used the dots because comments must be 15 characters, for whatever reason.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how `split` works: This is happening:

```
>>> ''.split(',')
['']
```

and it is a list of one element which is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the empty file returns `""`, and then splitting that empty string returns `[""]`, which has length 1.

Try this instead:

```
lines = open("empty.txt").readlines()
```